# Can you insert a new database connection in an existing database connection in OLEDB?

Tags: asp.net, oledb

I am creating a program in which I am trying to have a new database connection in an existing database connection in OLEDB using ASP.net. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection within connection" is likely not what you have in mind. But there is no issue with having both OleDb and SQLServer connections operating together in one ASP.NET application, you can add these 2 or many more connections to one app.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. Please make sure you close the connections after using by **using statement** or **close()** explicitly. More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using (OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString1))
using (OleDbConnection connection2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString2))
{
   connection1.Open();
   connection2.Open();
   // Do something
}
```